# java 8 Method References and Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, java-8

So I am experimenting with the upcomming jdk8 and encountered some oddities with the new Method references.

Is there a way to perform type checking on the arguments of an instance of a generic functional interface created from a Method reference?

The `Class` Object returned by `getClass()` of a Method reference has no Methods, Fields or meaningfull superclass or interfaces. Even the classname does not hold any meaningfull information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. I suppose that by method handle you mean method reference. A method reference does not have a type until you allocate it to a typed variable.

Say you have this method:

```
class A { public String m() { return ""; } }
```

Then `A::m` does not have a type: its type could be any functional interface that have a `String xxx();` method. For example it could be a:

```
Supplier<String> s = A::m;
```

in which case:

```
System.out.println(s.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()[0]);
```

prints:

```
public java.lang.Object mypackage.A$Lambda$1/1554547125.get()
```

which matches the erased signature of the method in the `Supplier` interface.

Comment: You are right. I missused `getDeclaredMethod`, forgot the parameter types.

Comment: Why do I get `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method m() from the type A` for `A::m` ?